# Want to skip number while performing for loop

Tags: python-2.7

While using for loop in python whatever range we initially define that is fixed.

In any case can we skip at some step like.code give `i={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`

I want

```
i={0,1,2,3,4,8,9}
        for i in range(0,10):
            print i
            if(i==4):
                i=i+3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list and in the loop check the list.

```
listinfo = [0,1,2,3,4,8,9]
for i in range(0,10):
    if i in listinfo:
         #do your stuff
```

Comment: Note that if larger amounts of values are involved, you should use a `set` or `range` (`xrange` in Python 2), both of which provide constant-time membership checking, unlike `list`.

Comment: I did not check the sequence of numbers. In this case your code is better.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is that every iteration of the for-loop begins by setting the value of `i` to the next item in the range, meaning that it doesn't matter how you set `i` during the loop's body.

Instead, you can have the loop body only execute for certain values like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i not in range(5, 8):
        print(i)
```